# How can I have a graphical 'diff' for git when working locally and also use diff via SSH?

Tags: git, ssh, diff, meld

I currently use [meld](http://meldmerge.org/) for `git diff`. I have configured it this way:

I've added **git-meld** to /bin:

```
#!/bin/bash
meld "$2" "$5"
```

made it executable

```
chmod +x git-meld
```

and added it to my git configuration:

```
git config --global diff.external git-meld
```

This works fine when I work locally. But when I'm logged in via SSH, I get an error message.

It would be great if I could use meld while I'm logged in via SSH, but using the standard diff would also be ok.

So my question is: **How can I have a graphical 'diff' for git when working locally and also use diff via SSH?**

Comment: is `ssh -X` out of question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `git-meld` script roughly like this:

```
if [ $DISPLAY ]; then
    exec meld "$2" "$5"
else
    exec diff "$2" "$5"
fi
```